# an real analysis problem of functions of improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis

is the  statement true/false.

Let $f$ be a continuous integrable function of $\mathbb{R}$ such that either $f(x) > 0$ or
$f(x) + f(x + 1) > 0$ for all x$ \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx>0$

is the above statement is true please help someone.

i am sorry that i could not wright it properly.the ingration will be from -infinity to infinity.thanks for help.

Comment: Consider integrating in both sides of $f(x)>0$ and $f(x)+f(x+1)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The first case is obvious.

For the second, note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)+f(x)dx\\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx\right]\\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y+1)dy\right]\\
&=& \frac {1}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)+f(x+1)dx\right] > 0,
\end{eqnarray*}
where the third equality follows from the change of variables $y := x-1$ and the last inequality is a direct consequence of $f(x)+f(x+1) > 0 \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

If for example you have a particular function like this that is positive when $x>0$ and negative when $x<0$, just split the integral in two at zero.
Where $f(x)>0$, it's obvious.
For $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x)dx$ just integrate your inequality:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x+1)dx>0$$
Then change variables u=x+1 and see that you now have $$2\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x)dx>0$$.

the general case just need you to split $R$ as many times as $f$ changes its sign.

Comment: It is obvious that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\, dx \geq 0$. The strict inequality is easy, but you need to exploit the assumption of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

The first is obviously true. The second I feel uneasy with; to give a totally random example: $$f(x)=\sin\pi x+\frac{1}{2}$$

This fills the condition $f(x)+f(x+1)>0$ but the integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\;dx$ fails to exist

(not sure if the word "integrable" disregards divergent *improper* integrals - please correct me if this is off-track)

Comment: It was assumed that $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user38773 Sorry. I thought integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ meant integrable for bounded intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. I didn't know $\sin$ and $\cos$ weren't "integrable on $\mathbb{R}$". Thanks for correcting!